# How to set height of container to 100% and show nav bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Having a terrible time trying to get react to render my page correctly

I have this

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

in my index.html I have

```
html, body, #root, #root>div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

inside router I have

```
            <>
                <GlobalStyle />
                <Nav/>
                <div>
                    <Router>
                        <Route component={Home} path="/" />
                    </Router>
                </div>
            </>
```

I want to display my nav on the top and then the components underneath to take up the rest of the screen space but NOT overflow and render a scroll. but whatever I try and do anything I cant seem to display both

I've tried adding a fixed height to the nav bar. `height: 100px !important` which works well for the navbar but then the rest of the content is about 60% of the page and there is an annoying div called. `<div tabindex="-1" style="outline: none">` which doesn't appear in my code anywhere. I think an accessibility thing? but when I set that to 100% and my container div below it to 100%, then it seems to work. however I cant set that to be 100% in my code so I'm left confused

I also assumed the code I set in the html would cascade down, so I'm confused why it's not cascading to this div? I wonder if setting the navbar is causing this?

anyway, all I want is a page that takes up the whole screen. but also renders a nav bar for 100px or so

any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: when nav is 100px so you should set div height to `calc(100vh - 100px)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex.

You can use the following css respectively:

For Parent component =>

```
display: flex, flex-direction: column;
```

For Nav component =>

```
height: 100px
```

For Sibling components =>

```
flex-grow: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use this css code:

```css
html, body, #root, #root>div {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```